# How do i style PHP validations

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

This my first time using PHP validation and my validations are working perfectly.
How do i style the validation, do i select the echo function or do i have to change my validation code to be able to style it. I have tried using a span and echoing out a error function and changing the echo's to the error function e.g $emailErr but not luck, the validations does not work. any suggestions?

HTML

```
            <!--                    <div id="first">-->
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value='' required><!--<span class="error"><!--<?php //echo $c_emailErr;            ?></span>-->
            <br>

            <figure>
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" value="" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><1--<?php //echo $c_pass1Err;            ?></span>-->
                <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" value="" placeholder=" Confirm password" maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><!--<?php //echo $c_pass2Err;            ?></span>-->
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </figure>
            <p class="remember_me">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">
            <br>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
  <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $reg_errors = array();
            $c_email = $_POST['email'];
            $c_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
            $c_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
            $emailErr = $pass1Err = $pass2Err = "";
           // $c_email = $c_pass1 = $c_pass2 = "";
           // Remove all illegal characters from email
           // $c_email = filter_var($c_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
           //Checking the email address
            if (!filter_var($c_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            echo("<b> This is a valid email address </b>");
            } else {
                echo("<b> Email is not a valid email address</b>");
            }
            if (strlen($c_pass1) <= '8') {
             echo "<b>Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!</br>";
             //check passwords
            }elseif ($c_pass1 == $c_pass2) {
            $q = "INSERT INTO      Cus_Register(Cus_Email,Cus_Password,Cus_confirm_password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
                //new
                // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
                //debugging
                //$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $c_email, $c_pass1, $c_pass2);
                if ($q) {
                    echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
            }
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: you use echo to add what ever style code is appropriate, php is server side.

Comment: You style your error messages like you would any other data displayed in the browser - using HTML and CSS. You should separate it from your server side code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you had  tag for text  and you have the code

```html
<?
echo '<t>this is some text';
?>
```

to add styles all you simply have to do is style the "t" tag like so in css

```css
t{
  font-size:3px;
  background-color:red;
  // other styles
  }
```